# PHP not displaying errors on live environment, shows blank screen

Tags: linux, nginx, php

I have 2 environments, local and live

on local i am running:
apache
php 5.2.9

on live i'm running:
nginx (fpm)
php 5.3.5

i have tried setting:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
```

this allows all errors on both servers, but on my live server i'm not seeing some errors, for example:

```
require('test.php);  //missing single quote
```

gives me a blank screen, but on my local it gives me a notice and fatal error(because of the the require)

if i try to require a file that doesn't exist i get fatal errors on both environments.

I have access to change the configs and error reporting and display_errors are beign set correctly.

Any ideas?

Comment: FYI, setting error reporting in PHP won't work, since the parse errors are thrown before that code is even executed.  You'd need to change php.ini, .htaccess, or user.ini...

Comment: I think the real key note here is that you should have most of your parser type errors, like a critical missing quote worked out before you push to the live site. Or even setup a staging site, so it goes Dev -> Stage -> Production  this will greatly decrease those type of critical errors to production / live versions, given it was tested on the Dev box and Staging box.

Comment: my wording was incorrect for illustration purposes, its actually my dev server which isn't showing the parse errors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those kid of errors are critical. And their debugging information is also critical and potentially vulnerable to attacks.

Some hosts keep [display_startup_errors off](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-startup-errors) due to this.